# Jetpack Compose: Managing Shared UI State

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
typealias Actions = @Composable () -> Unit

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SampleAppTheme {
                var currentScreen by remember { mutableStateOf(Screen.A) }
                var title by remember { mutableStateOf("Screen A") }
                var action by remember { mutableStateOf<Actions>({}) }
                
                Scaffold(
                     topBar = {
                        TopAppBar(
                            title = {
                                Text(title)
                            },
                            actions = {
                                action()
                            }
                        )
                    }
                 ) {
                    Crossfade(current = currentScreen) { screen ->
                         when (screen) {
                             Screen.A -> {
                                MyScreen(
                                    name = "A",
                                    buttonName = "to Screen B",
                                    onNext = {
                                        currentScreen = Screen.B
                                        title = "Screen B"
                                        action = {
                                             IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                                                Icon(asset = Icons.Sharp.Home)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                            Screen.B -> {
                                MyScreen(
                                    name = "B",
                                    buttonName = "to Screen C",
                                    onNext = {
                                        currentScreen = Screen.C
                                        title = "Screen B"
                                        action = {
                                            IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                                                Icon(asset = Icons.Sharp.Close)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                            Screen.C -> {
                                MyScreen(
                                    name = "C",
                                    buttonName = "to Screen A",
                                    onNext = {
                                        currentScreen = Screen.A
                                        title = "Screen A"
                                        action = {}
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum class Screen {
    A, B, C
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    name: String,
    buttonName: String,
    onNext: () -> Unit,
) {
    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(24.dp),
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            text = "I am in screen $name!",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3
        )
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            onClick = onNext
        ) {
            Text(text = buttonName)
        }
    }
}
```

So with this code I have the following screen:

[image: ScreenA][image: ScreenB][image: ScreenC]

Notice that I am able to change the `Actions` in the `TopAppBar`, depending on the Current Screen by doing:

```
MyScreen(
    name = "B",
    buttonName = "to Screen C",
    onNext = {
        currentScreen = Screen.C
        title = "Screen B"
        // This right here!!!! -------------------
        action = { 
            IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                Icon(asset = Icons.Sharp.Close)
            }
        }
        // This right here!!!! -------------------
    }
)
```

1. My first question is whether this is a correct way to this?
2. For the second question, I kinda feel the values I am setting in the previous screen should instead be the responsibility of the current screen instead. so I tried doing this instead?

```html
Screen.B -> {
    // This right here!!!! -------------------
    onActive {
         title = "Screen B"
         action = { 
             IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                 Icon(asset = Icons.Sharp.Home)
             }
         }
    }
    // This right here!!!! -------------------
    MyScreen(
         name = "B",
         buttonName = "to Screen C",
         onNext = {
             currentScreen = Screen.C
         }
    )
}
```

So now, the responsibility of setting up the state is on the current screen and not the screen before it like before.

Is this better?

After some testing: Apparently moving from Screen A -> Screen B -> Screen C makes it that `onActive {  }` gets called the wrong order. So there are states where Screen B have Screen A as its title... Screen C have Screen B as its title and so on...

Just realize even the first approach has flaws as you also have to set the state when going back to a screen.. lets say when doing... Screen A -> Screen B -> Screen C -> press back (Screen B)... Now the state is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I guess this problem could be solved using Jetpack Navigation for Compose.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation

Maybe this post help you out...

https://afzaln.com/intro-to-jetpack-compose-navigation/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)